# Setting up router on wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, signal, signal-strength

I am living in an apartment connected to a wireless network. I don't know anything about the physical router. There is no ethernet wall jack. Can I purchase a new router, set it up on this connection, then connect to it through an ethernet cable to attain a faster/more stable connection?

Comment: You have to supply us with more information.  *You not knowing anything about the router, means, this question cannot be answered.*

Comment: I'm asking if it is possible to set up a new router on a wireless connection without knowing anything about the router that currently provides me with this wireless connection

Comment: If you know nothing about the router then you can not purchase a router that's capatible since you don't know anything about the router or modem.  It's possible to extend a network but you need to know something about the hardware on the network to do that.  So find out about the hardware....

Comment: What does it take for a router to be compatible in this situation?

Comment: Knowing the make and model of the router

Comment: Lets say I know the make and model of the router. How would you figure out what kind of new router I would need for it to be compatible?

Comment: Update your question to include that information and I will answer your question.

Comment: Are you sure there *is* a router in the apartment?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What would the other options be?

Comment: @Infamous911 For example, there could be a router for the floor or the building that you have no access to.

Comment: Yes that is what I think the situation is

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely [devices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004UAKCS6) that can connect a wired Ethernet device to a wireless network, but there's no reason to assume that any such device would give you a more stable connection to the wireless network than the built-in wireless interfaces on the devices you already own. The radio and antennas in such wired->wireless Ethernet adapter could be just as crappy as the radio and antennas in your laptop or tablet or smartphone.

The only clear advantage of using such a device is when the place you like to sit when working on your laptop is a place where the signal is poor. You could position the wired->wireless Ethernet adapter in a place where you know it always gets good signal, and then run a long Ethernet cable from it to wherever you want to sit when actually working on your laptop.